# Why can Japanese Godan verbs only have nine possible consonant sounds before the final -u?

Tags: etymology, verbs, japanese

The dictionary form of Japanese verbs always ends in a -u syllable. Ichidan (one row or *single-step* in German) verbs will always end in -る (-ru, e.g. 食べる, *taberu*, to eat) while godan (five rows or *five-step* in German) verbs can end in any of the following:

- -う (-u) as in 会う (*au*, to meet)
- -く (-ku) as in 書く (*kaku*, to write)
- -ぐ (-gu) as in 泳ぐ (*oyogu*, to swim)
- -す (-su) as in 話す (*hanasu*, to speak)
- -つ (-tsu) as in 立つ (*tatsu*, to stand)
- -ぬ (-nu) as *only* (!) in 死ぬ (*shinu*, to die)
- -ぶ (-bu) as in 遊ぶ (*asobu*, to play)
- -む (-mu) as in 読む (*yomu*, to read); or
- -る (-ru) as in 有る (*aru*, to exist/to be/to have)

It is notable that -う (-u) is actually from -wu, which can only be seen in the (w)a-form (used e.g. in negation 会わない rather than *会あない) as all other w- syllables have merged with their respective Ø- forms. Furthermore, it is interesting that among voiced/unvoiced pairs only -く (-ku) and -ぐ (-gu) coexist as verb endings; -ず (-zu) and -づ (-dzu) do not form verbs to the best of my knowledge and neither do -ふ (-fu) or -ぷ (pu). Verbs ending in -ゆ (-yu) or an -う (-u) which is not actually a historic -wu seem not to exist at all. Finally, according to my grammar book there is only a single verb that ends in -ぬ.

What are the origins of this perceived imbalance? How come only one voiced/unvoiced pair exists in contemporary Japanese and are there any mechanisms that explain the absence of the other missing syllables e.g. by mergers? And why is it -ぶ but -つ and -す?

Comment: The restriction you mention was already in place in Old Japanese, whose yodan verb roots could only end in /p, t, k, b, g, m, s and r/ (p-roots eventually becoming w-roots). 死 /sin-/ was an irregular verb that merged into the yodan class when its dictionary form was levelled from /sinuru/ to /sinu/ in late Middle Japanese. Other irregular consonant roots ended in /k, r and s/, patterning with the yodan class. The cause of this restriction might be found in Proto-Japonic reconstructions, but my cursory search didn't find anything

Answer (score 5):

Japanese verb roots show a strong tendency to be native rather than borrowed vocabulary. In native Japanese vocabulary, original *p was lenited to [w] between vowels (based on the historical spelling of syllables with this [w] sound and the alternative development of *p to a voiceless fricative in word or morpheme-initial position, this medial [w] from *p seems to have passed through an intermediate stage of a voiceless labial fricative [ɸ]).

Because of these sound changes (*p > ɸ followed by VɸV > VwV), there is no regular source of intervocalic /p/, /h/ or /ɸ/ in native Japanese vocabulary (although these sounds do show up intervocalically in some kinds of borrowed words, reduplicated mimetic words, or compound words). I think that explains fairly well the absence of -fu and -pu verbs.

I don’t know whether there are explanations for the other gaps that you mention. I remember reading that some Japanese verbs have switched classes between time periods: I don’t know whether that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not qualified to comment on the rest, but I do want to note that both *-zu* and *-nu* are [verb conjugations in classical Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC).  For ichidan verbs, both these forms are formed by replacing the *-ru* with *-zu/nu*:

- 見る *miru* "to see"
- 見ず *mizu* "without seeing" (modern Japanese 見なくて *minakute*)
- 見ぬ *minu* "not seeing" (modern Japanese 見ない *minai*)

As you can see, **if *-nu* or *-zu* verbs were common, they would easily be confused with the negated forms of ichidan verbs**.  Godan verbs, though, are conjugated the same way as *-nai*, so there's less potention for confusion:

- 死ぬ *shinu* "to die"
- 死なず *shinazu* "without dying" (modern Japanese 死なないで *shinanaide*)
- 死なぬ *shinanu* "not dying" (modern Japanese 死なない *shinanai*)

Comment: I don’t subscribe to your bolded sentence. Chance overlaps between different grammatical forms are common and not a problem because context exists and because different inflections are acknowledged in our brains. For example the French verbs *dormir* and *finir* each have a form where the final *r* is replaced by *t:* *il dormit* versus *il finit*. However, the first is past tense and the second is either present or past tense. (Present tense of *dormir* is *il dort*.) Likewise, Japanese are fine distinguishing between 来る、切る and 着る even though their forms overlap.